# Converting generic class to base type

Tags: c#, generics

This is the interface definition:

```
public interface IEtlProcess<out X, out X1, out Y, out Y1, out Z, out Z1> : IEtlProcessC<X, X1, Y, Y1>
    where X : IExtractJob<X1>
    where X1 : IExtractResult
    where Y : ITransformJob<X1, Y1>
    where Y1 : ITransformResult
    where Z : ILoadJob<Y1, Z1>
    where Z1 : ILoadResult
{
    Y TransformJob { get; }

    Z LoadJob { get; }

    ExtractDefinition ExtractDefinition { get; }
}
```

and the implementation look this this:

```
public class StatisticsEtlProcess : IEtlProcess<StatisticsExtractJob, StatisticsExtractResult, StatisticsTransformJob, StatisticsTransformResult, StatisticsLoadJob, StatisticsLoadResult>
{
    public IServiceConfiguration ServiceConfiguration { get; set; }

    public StatisticsExtractJob ExtractJob
    {
        get
        {
            return new StatisticsExtractJob(ExtractDefinition);
        }
    }

    public StatisticsLoadJob LoadJob
    {
        get
        {
            return new StatisticsLoadJob(ExtractDefinition);
        }
    }

    public StatisticsTransformJob TransformJob
    {
        get
        {
            return new StatisticsTransformJob(ExtractDefinition);
        }
    }

    public ExtractDefinition ExtractDefinition
    {
        get
        {
            return new ExtractDefinition();
        }
    }
}
```

nothing too fancy, but unfortunatelly I'm having a few issues while trying to fit the concrete implementation into a list of this type:

```
    private IList<IEtlProcess<IExtractJob<IExtractResult>, IExtractResult, ITransformJob<IExtractResult, ITransformResult>,
        ITransformResult, ILoadJob<ITransformResult, ILoadResult>, ILoadResult>> _etlProcesses;
```

I created a few other interface to help me debug the issue:

```
public interface IEtlProcessC<out X, out X1, out Y, out Y1> : IEtlProcessB<X, X1>
    where X : IExtractJob<X1>
    where X1 : IExtractResult
    where Y : ITransformJob<X1, Y1>
    where Y1 : ITransformResult
{ }

public interface IEtlProcessB<out X, out X1> : IEtlProcessA
    where X : IExtractJob<X1>
    where X1 : IExtractResult
{
    X ExtractJob { get; }
}

public interface IEtlProcessA
{ }
```

And I can get this to work:

```
var aaa = (IEtlProcessB<IExtractJob<IExtractResult>, IExtractResult>)instance;
```

but not this:

```
var bbb = (IEtlProcessC<IExtractJob<IExtractResult>, IExtractResult, ITransformJob<IExtractResult, ITransformResult>, ITransformResult>)instance;
```

which basically raises a cast excection. The intance variable is an intance of the StatisticsEtlProcess type. The generic template seems to be right, but I'm definitely missing something. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 1**

```
public interface IExtractJob<out T> where T : IExtractResult
{
    T Extract(FileInfo file);
}

public interface ILoadJob<T, out TZ> where T : ITransformResult where TZ : ILoadResult
{
    TZ Load(T transformResult);
}

public interface ITransformJob<T, out TZ> : IJob where T : IExtractResult where TZ : ITransformResult
{
    TZ Transform(T extractResult);
}
```

Comment: Do `IExtractJob` and `ITransformJob` also have covariant parameters? My guess is that `ITransformJob` doesn't, and unless they are all covariant, it won't work (and it shouldn't).

Comment: Yes, `ITransformJob<T, out TZ>` needs to be `ITransformJob<out T, out TZ>` if you want to cast like this.

Comment: T can't be marked as out because it is used as a paramenter, that would't work it won't even compile. The only way I can think of is marking the method generic rather then the class, but that is rather ugly.

Comment: Well, you are probably aware that this design is slightly "suspicious" in the first place. The reason I wrote you need `out` is that this ensures covariance. If you have a variable of the base type with all the base interface parameters `IEtlProcess<IExtractJob<...`, then you have a variable which should be able to return **any** instance of `ITransformJob<T, out TZ>`, which can accept any instance of `IExtractResult`. Your derived class can only accept a specific class implementing `IExtractResult`, and that's why you cannot cast.

Comment: The design is alright, it is basically a flow in which the return type of one method in a given class is the input of another method in another classe and all those classes belong to a process. If I remove the constraints from the Job class, the is no way to stop for example different implementations of IExtractResult being used in the same Job which is what I need to avoid. The design is complex yes, but without if I use interfaces in the method definitions, I will lose a lot of type checking

Comment: Any class which must know exact types of 6 other interfaces is hardly in the spirit of OOP, not to mention DI. You gained type safety with generics, but that's the only thing you gained. Then you have three separate E/T/L interfaces which are functionally completely equivalent and could be replaced by a single `ITransform<Tfrom, Tto>` (or `IConvert<Tfrom, Tto>`, or however you want to call this interface).

Comment: But what functionality should this class have, apart from serving as a template to fill in concrete classes? Is it here to provide progress info? Then it does it the wrong way, because its callers have no business knowing about concrete instances of these jobs except for perhaps their name, progress or errors. Should it manage these jobs, i.e. start and stop the whole process? Then this is the interface it should expose.

Comment: How does it do it in a wrong way if the callers work against interfaces only? There will supposedly exist more than one job, and that class is not used as a template because different jobs have different needs but they all share the same workflow. Those definitions are loaded into a generic list, and the problem is that the DI container isn't able to resolve  the classes that implement the Job interface, and that's where the issue is coming from. The job runner have no knowledge about the concrete classes whatsoever.

Comment: What I'm saying is that callers cannot work against generic non-covariant interfaces without knowing actual types of their generic parameters. Your `StatisticsEtlProcess.TransformJob` is not of type `ITransformJob<IExtractResult, ITransformResult>`, it's a more specific type `ITransform<StatisticsExtractResult, StatisticsTransformResult>`. Since your callers cannot know what to pass to `ITransformJob<Tx, Ty>.Transform`, it means they are not supposed to access this interface anyway. Or, the interface shouldn't be generic, in which case you need to have a bunch of runtime casting internally.

Comment: And they are not. They call the generic interface with interface parameters not the concrete classes. Also you don't need to know the parameters, you can create an open generic type and use the base interfaces. Thanks for your reply, but I'm not here to discuss the design, the disign is alright.

Comment: In that case, I'm sure the design is alright and you won't have any issues casting to the generic interface.

Comment: The cast is not necessary anymore, thanks.